# ArgoCD setup issue on EKS

Tags: amazon-ec2, argocd, gitops

I have tried to setup argocd application on the Eks environment using EC2 Linux, I try to login using load balancer, and when I look into the status its showing unknown.

[image: Connection status showing unknown]

I am expecting that the status should be successful.

Comment: There's no chance you'll get an answer here. Better ask on ServerFault for instance as this is not a developer question.

Comment: That being said, I'd look into argocd logs to troubleshoot. Could be an account issue.